# how to configure terminal to always launch on secondary monitor?

Tags: 16.04, multiple-monitors, gnome-terminal

I have a dual monitor setup. gnome-terminal window placement is set to smart. When I launch gnome-terminal window is placed on the monitor where it has been launched.

## Question

How can I set gnome-terminal window to be placed on a specific monitor?

## Further detail

I am using Ubuntu 16.04

I tried to use compizconfig-settings-manager:

[Place Windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9dTN.png)

I am not sure if the configuration is correct, but it seems to have its position relative to a single screen.

## Goal

Launching the terminal with something like `gnome-terminal -x --geometry=120x80+50+50` would be preferred. Alternative, a system-wide configuration can be used.

Comment: Your configuration has the command set to be starting at 50+50 on your primary monitor.  If your primary monitor is say 1920x1080, then if you wanted the terminal to start on the second monitor it would be something like `gnome-terminal --geometry=120x80+1920+50`  or change the `1920` to a greater number to start it more like `1970` which would be your original 50+1920

Comment: @Terrance this works perfectly, exactly what i was looking for thank you. If you make your comment an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`+0+0` is the starting upper left corner. Your configuration has the command set to be starting at `50+50` on your primary monitor, which is `50` to the right and `50` down. If your primary monitor is say `1920x1080`, then if you wanted the terminal to start on the second monitor it would be something like `gnome-terminal --geometry=120x80+1920+50` or change the `1920` to a greater number to start it more like `1970` which would be your original `50+1920`.

Hope this helps!